# Creating a struct causes weird behaviors in remix ide

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

Problem:
Remix produces weird behaviors with a string param followed by an array param

Reproduce:

```
contract ItemMarket is ERC721 {
  struct Item {
    string name;
    uint[3] others;
  }

  Item[] public items;

  function createItem(string _name, uint[6] _others) public {
    uint tokenId = items.push(Item({name: _name, traits:_traits})) - 1;
  }
}
```

When you call createItem() in remix with the arguments `"hello", [1,2,3]` the first argument gets converted to `\u0000`. The same function call with the same arguments works fine when interacted with the contract through MEW

Comment: It's a bug in Remix: https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/591

Answer (score 2):

This now works in the latest version of Remix IDE:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token.sol";

contract ItemMarket is ERC721 {
  struct Item {
    string name;
    uint[3] traits;
  }

  Item[] public items;

  function createItem(string memory name, uint[3] memory traits) public {
    items.push(Item({name:name, traits:traits})) - 1;
  }
}
```